# How to block all users/visitors in my website that disable javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got a lot of bots on my website. The problem is that they increase our bounce rate which makes us look bad for google. If users bounce they dont like the site. That is a bad signal for SEO

most of these bots have javascript disabled. On the other hand no real user disables javascript. is it possible block all users/visitors in my website that disable javascript? Thanks

Comment: Wrong question. Let me help you with this: "How can I fix our web analytics software, so that it ignores bots?"

Comment: Some real users disable javascript too, it may be a bad signal for those user if you kick them of your site.

Comment: I'm sure blocking all bots / no-js-visitors (_Which includes Google's_) will increase your Google ranking! \*Cough*

Comment: And about that "No real user disables Javascript" you are in dire need of reading this: https://gds.blog.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/

Comment: Maybe this would be worth a read.. http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_stop_automated_spam-bots_using_.htaccess

Comment: If user has JavaScript disabled, Google is not tracking them already (because it uses JS to do so), so I don't think they are contributing towards your overall bounce rate.

Comment: Boldewyn sorry but my question is not wrong. Thank you

Comment: Pierre.Sassoulas yes thee are some users and those users are the one i want to block.

Comment: Boldewyn i will read it and will give you update. Thanks

Comment: pbwned i will also read it and give you update as soon as am done reading the link you gave. Thanks

Comment: martynasma am not sure about your point but for now I need to block the user that disable javascript. Thanks

Comment: @martynasma What about iframes/images in `<noscript>` tag?

Comment: @Justinas I don't think GA has that fallback in their officially-generated tracking code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is one file that is named `robots.txt` to prevent certain robots from accessing your site. More information about that [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

If you wish to prevent some content viewable without JS, just load it using JS (ajax) or use CSS to apply overlay for your web and remove it with JS after page loads.

---

Robots have no idea if there is any user in world (e.g. zombie apocalypse). You have to decide what you want - *detect if JS is working* **OR** *detect robot and prevent it from accessing site*. **Your google analytics code will not work without JS if placed as simple script in header**. If GA code contains `<noscript>` tag, remove it and any user that don't have JS will not send any information to GA.

Comment: Thank you Justinas. I will give you update as soon test and i read the link you gave me.

Comment: Justinas i think the robots.text will solve my problem but how does robots will detect if the user javascript is disable? Thanks

Comment: @MarkAnthonyBarangan: robots.txt is a simple text file. It works because bots (like Google, Bing etc.) are supposed to read it and not crawl the links/url listed in that text file. It's a voluntary thing. An evil person can of course write bots that ignore that file. An evil person can also write a bot using phantomjs or selenium which would have javascript enabled.

Comment: @MarkAnthonyBarangan: If you doubt such programmers (who use phantomjs to scrape websites) exist let me tell you that these days I tend to use phantomjs to scrape websites because too many websites generate content with javascript making old-school screen scraping next to useless.